# Router as default gateway but why the ip always recommended .1 but not .2 or .3?

Tags: networking, ip, router, default, gateway

I know .1 as for default gateway but why not recommend to use 2 to 254. My gateway is 192.168.77.1

Comment: A gateway (router) is a host on the network that knows how to forward packets to other networks. Just like any other host, it can be addressed with any valid host address on the network. Some people always use the first valid host address (not always `.1`), and some people always use the last valid host address (not always `.254`). (Remember that not all networks are `/24` networks that are `.1` to `.254` for valid host addresses.). It can be any valid host address, but you should consistently do it the same way to avoid future problems.

Comment: It's just a "convention" or "rule of thumb", not a hard "rule"; don't assume it.  Probably based on human nature -- start counting at the bottom, and start configuring at the most important node (the gateway) first.  This only applies to stub networks, obviously.